# Neovim popup window with type signatures on mouse hover in haskell code (like in Visual Studio Code)

Tags: neovim

I install Neovim with coc-nvim plugin and haskell language server. Now I have autocomplete and syntax highlighting. But I want to see type signatures when I move mouse on functions and other names (like in Visual Studio Code).

How to achive this with coc-nvim or any other plugin in Neovim?